# Android Java: List of items, when click on specific remove that specific

Tags: java, android, list

In Android Java:
How would one make it so it fetches specific data from SQlite dabatase, then prints it out in rows( each row has it's own id as it's different entry). And when user clicks on that item/row it will show menu: Remove, Edit, Cancel?
Any ideas?

I mean in PHP/HTML I would use GET method and links like:

```
<li><a href="view.php?itemid=15">Item 15</a></li>
<li><a href="view.php?itemid=35">Item 35</a></li>
```

Then on view.php file i would use like:

```
$selectedItem = $_GET['itemid'];
```

Then if user clicked remove, it would cast something like:

```
DETELETE FROM ItemList WHERE `id`='$selectedItem';
```

But how can I make this using Java in Android?

P.S - List is not a dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into it.